# How to scroll ListView row to top of the screen?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile-development

I am using ListView to render my data on page.

How to scroll ListView row to top of the screen (visible) when it clicked?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question, do you want to move the row clicked to the top of the `ListView` or scroll the `ListView` itself to the top?

Comment: I need to scroll ListView. Example when I clicked to row #3, this row must be on top.

Comment: One way or the other you'll have to use [`ListView.scrollTo()`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Components/ScrollView/ScrollView.js#L378), which can scroll the `ListView` to a precise position (given `x` and `y`).

Comment: But how can I know which position I need to scroll? Can you edit my code with ListView.scrollTo() ? https://rnplay.org/apps/8baZSA